# Add values from another array to calculate cumsum in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum

Is there a way of creating this type of cumulative sum in numpy without using a for loop?

```
y[0] = x[0]
y[1] = y[0] + x[1]
y[2] = y[1] + x[2]
```

I'm confused about how to use the cumsum function in order to calculate the cumulative sum of array y while adding the values from array x.

Comment: That didn't seem to work because it's calculating the cumsum of y and then adding x to the result. What I'm looking for is something like `np.cumsum(y + x)` but I can't seem to find any tips anywhere.

Comment: What about `y += x + np.array([0, *y[:-1,]])`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Here's the code to do it:

```
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.zeros(10)
z = x + y
cum_sum = np.cumsum(z)
```